# Given an affine space and a plane, how can I find the basis of the plane with respect to the affine space?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

I have the affine space $A:(O, B=(e_1,2e_2,e_1+e_3))$ and a plane $\alpha:x-y+z=0$ how can I find the basis of that plane in the given affine space?

I found the basis of the plane: $((1,1,0),(0,1,1))$, but I don't understand the relation with the basis of the affine space and what I have to do with it.

Comment: You're given a different basis to use which is $B \neq \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ so you'll need to express the answer as linear combinations of those vectors, not the canonical basis vectors.

Comment: @CyclotomicField so my basis is $B=\{(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(1,0,1)\}$ for convenience let these vectors be $e'_1, e'_2, e'_3$, the answer would be $\{(e'_1+\frac{1}{2}e'_2),(\frac{1}{2}e'_2+e'_3-e'_1)\}$.
Is it correct?

Comment: A good way to double check is to substitute those vectors into the equation and see if they work.